# Vectors / Linearly independent question

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

an easy question that I completely understand, just not sure how to algebraically prove.
$u,v,w$ are vectors in $R^3$
given $u\times v +v\times w + w\times u=0$

I need to prove that {u,v,w} are linearly dependent.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: are those $x$'s cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: maybe not since then the claim is false (although the negation of the claim is true - perhaps you meant linearly dependent?)

Comment: @countinghaus - if $x$ is indeed $\times$, then $u,v,w$ are dependent.

Comment: @nbubis I agree - so then what could OP mean? what operation $x$ is there on vectors such that the cyclic sum of three vectors $x$'d pairwise against one another equalling zero implies INdependence?

Comment: i'm sorry guys. it is cross product. and i meant to prove that they ARE dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $v\times v=0$:
$$u\times v +v\times w + w\times u=u\times(v-w)+v\times w-v\times v=
(u-v)\times(v-w)=0$$
Meaning that:
$$(u-v)=c(v-w)$$
Or that:
$$u=c(v-w)+v$$

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: a nonzero vector $x$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ can't be perpendicular to three linearly independent vectors $u, v, w$. Proof: three linearly independent vectors make a basis, so we can write $x = a_1u + a_2v + a_3w$. Dotting both sides with $x$ tells you that $x$ is 0.

Main result: Dot both sides of the given equality with $u$. We have $u\cdot (v \times w) = 0$. Thus $v \times w$ is perpendicular to $u, v,$ and $w$.

It follows that either $u, v,$ and $w$ are linearly dependent or $v \times w = 0$, but in this latter case certainly $u, v, w$ are linearly dependent since $v, w$ are.